# how do i show a document depending on drop down options selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to provide sample PDFs to customers according to their selection from drop down menus that I make available to them.

I have created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9hqKN/1/) to try and show you what I am trying to achieve.

My HTML:

```
<p>Please select from the options below to view a sample Investment Cost Analysis:</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>
  <label for="type">* Combined Income:</label>
  <select name="income" id="income">
    <option selected="selected">- Please Select -</option>
    <option value="$30,000 - $80,000">$30,000 - $80,000</option>
    <option value="$80,000 - $180,000">$80,000 - $180,000</option>
    <option value="$180,000+">$180,000+</option>
  </select>
</p>
<p>
<label for="type">* Property Type:</label>
<select name="type" id="type">
  <option selected="selected">- Please Select -</option>
  <option value="house">House</option>
  <option value="unit">Apartment / Unit</option>
</select>
</p>
<p>
<label for="price">* Property Price:</label>
<select name="price" id="price">
  <option selected="selected">- Please Select -</option>
  <option value="$350,000">$350,000</option>
  <option value="$400,000">$400,000</option>
  <option value="$450,000">$450,000</option>
  <option value="$500,000">$500,000</option>
</select>
</p>
<p>
  <input type="submit" name="show" id="show" value="Show Sample" />
</p>
```

How do I make it so that depending on what options are selected, it shows the correct file? I would also like to make sure that **ALL 3** options are selected before the Show Sample button will work.

I know this is going to take some JavaScript but that is where I am stuck. I have no idea where to start with the JavaScript.

Comment: trying to add it but it wont let me - http://jsfiddle.net/9hqKN/1/

Comment: given the mock code ..check and get back to me if you have any doubt

Answer (score 1):

On change of dropdown function change the href of link

```
$("#mydropdown").change(function(e) {

var dropdown value = $("#mydropdown").value();

//switch condition 
if(){
$("mylink").attr("href", "your file path"); 
//TODO 
}else if (){

}

 });
```

Comment: I am not sure how this works sorry, I am not very good with Javascript. Any chance you can provide a jsfiddle with the 3 options selected so I can see how it works?

Comment: for 3 combos ..you need to add more number of conditions ... before setting href attributes

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple example.

**Update:** 
Obviously if the user's Browser doesn't have a PDF viewer, this would force a download window.

**HTML**:

```
<select id="pdfs">
    <option value="http://example.com/docs1.pdf">PDF 1</option>
    <option value="http://example.com/docs2.pdf">PDF 2</option>
    <option value="http://example.com/docs3.pdf">PDF 3</option>
</select>
```

**JS**:

```
var selectElem = document.getElementById('pdfs');

selectElem.onchange = function() {
  window.location = selectElem[selectElem.selectedIndex].value;
};
```

Comment: I can see how this works but I want the customers to select from the options I am making available to them rather than just show PDF1, PDF2, etc for download as you cant see what the reference point is to the document otherwise?

Comment: Well you can replace "PDF 1" with the actual link if you want to but that's ugly. I would say that you aren't looking solely for a drop-down solution then - perhaps something in combination with another element. What about if we create a link on the fly with the URL that the user chose from the dropdown? That would be a good solution. The steps would be like this: (Choose a PDF from dropdown) -> (Click on generated link to download/view)

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/9hqKN/2/

```
$('#show').hide();

$('select').change(function () {
  var income = $('#income').val();
  var type = $('#type').val();
  var price = $('#price').val();

  if (income == 0 || type == 0 || price == 0) {
    $('#show').hide();
  } else {
    $('#show').show();
  }
});
```

there is one edit i put value to `0` for `all first option` in each `<select>`

Comment: I am having a bad start to the day so asking probably a really simple question here but how do i actually link to a document if i was to select the first option in each drop down when i click on the Show Sample button?